# ignore debugger; statements in Node.js, during debug session

Tags: node.js, debugging, breakpoints

I have a codebase where I have quite a number of

```
debugger;
```

statements. Sometimes I debug, and I actually just want to skip all of the debugger; statements and continue only to the manually set breakpoints that I have chosen for the debugging session, is there some setting by chance with Node.js to do that?

In other words, I would like to consider the `debugger;` statements to be long-term placeholders, but for certain debugging sessions I would like to ignore those long-term placeholders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trick I've used in the past is to just use babel to strip out debugger statements:

See:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-remove-debugger

Comment: Do you have also the link for the GitHub page ? The link on npmjs is not working anymore.

Answer (score 6):

That can be done with the chrome devtools.

You can do:

```
node --inspect --debug-brk index.js
```

that will generate something like this:

```
chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_file/@60cd6e859b9f557d2312f5bf532f6aec5f284980/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=localhost:9229/9c2e4f37-4c3a-4477-b8da-2399c5d9819e
```

Just copy and paste that on chrome.

There is an option to disable/enable all the break points, and chrome will remember all the breakpoints that you set previously.

Please check: [`--inspect`](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27#.cuhr9xlqe) for more info.

Comment: Chrome won't allow  you to disable just `debugger` statements? Only breakpoints all together, regardless of origin.

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty way (its for debug so, its fine really) is to stick something like the following script in scripts/debugger.js

```
require.extensions['.js'] = function(module, filename) {
  var content = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8').replace(/debugger/g, [
    '(function() {',
    '  if (__debugger) {',
    '    debugger;',
    '  }',
    '})',
  ].join('\n'));

  module._compile(content, filename);
};
```

then start node with `node -r ./scripts/debugger`

Using a global variable here so that it can be enabled/disabled from the debugger repl or chrome's repl if debugging with `--inspect`.

Technically require.extensions is deprecated, but it's not going to be removed and it works as intended here.